# Auto filling a form in arcpad

Tags: arcpad, toolbar, vb

I am looking to figure out how to auto-fill a custom form at the click of a button. Basically i have a toolbar where if I click the button and a point on the map a form pops up and gives me a bunch of options. To make it easier I am looking to have a few pre-made forms so if i click on lets say a corn icon on the toolbar and then click on the map, The form would pop up with all the corn details already filled on the form so you just need to hit OK  and it places the point.
As an example this is how the form looks when clicked. I need it to be filled out so when I click on my black bean button it comes out filled as 
LandUse = Agr. - Pulses and 
Crop Type = Beans - Black Beans

The repeat attributes toolbar will not work because it does not save the Crop Type but only the LandUse.

[image: dropdown]

Comment: Is each icon on your toolbar related to one layer or multiple layers?

Comment: It is related to one layer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the `Repeat Attributes` button. To turn on `Repeate Attributes` fill out a form with the required values and and at the bottom of the form click the `Repeat Attributes` button. Every time you open a new form it will now autofill these values.

You can do this for multiple datatypes as well using the Quick Capture toolbar. If you symbolize by category then each category on the quick capture toolbar can have its own set of repeat attributes.

Comment: The repeat attributes does not keep the sub category. As an example it will keep the land use category but not the crop type.

Comment: I am using an edit form in a .apl file and the toolbar is an .apa file. Would it be easier to add in the toolbar in the .apl file and then add it all into there or should i leave the buttons in the .apa?